# All files missing from Ubuntu 14.04 install

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have no idea about its installation. But I have alloted 20Gb space for it in `C:` drive.

When I plug in my USB Ubuntu boots up, but still asks me to try Ubuntu or install it.
I am assuming I have installed it.

Yesterday I installed Ruby on Rails, downloaded few pictures etc… Today when I open my system nothing is there. Not even my Wi-Fi password has been saved. It looks like a fresh machine. Every time I shut down I am losing all my files.

I completely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry typo error !

Comment: Yes I am running ubuntu from usb

Comment: but I am loosing  all my files are shutting down the pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple mistake to make, especially if you are new to Ubuntu. You are running a *Live CD/USB*. Any changes you make are temporary, and are lost when you shutdown or reboot. You are basically doing this: [Try Ubuntu before you install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

You need to actually *install it on to your hard drive*. When you start the system next, click on the **Install button**, instead of the **Try**. This will then run you through the steps necessary to instal Ubuntu on your hard drive. Once that has finished, power down, remove the USB stick, and then start the PC as normal.  Now, when you create any files, they will be saved permanently and be there the next time you reboot.

This page   [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) should help you:

> **Outline**
>
> The general procedure to install Ubuntu (or Ubuntu flavour, Kubuntu,
>   Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) from a USB flash drive is:
>
> 1. Acquire the correct Ubuntu installation files ('the ISO')
> 2. Put Ubuntu onto your USB flash drive
> 3. Configure your computer to boot from USB flash drive and boot from
>      it
> 4. [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389) before installing it
> 5. Install Ubuntu to your internal drive (hard disk drive or solid
>      state drive).